# Python web crawler no output

Tags: python, web-crawler

I tried to create my first python web crawler (learned it from thenewboston). I dont get any error messages, but also no output..
Heres my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def sportpoint_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.sportpoint.lt/vyrams-1?page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'atl '}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1

sportpoint_spider(1)
```

Comment: Could you add `print(plain_text)` statement after `plain_text = source_code.text` and post results?

Comment: it printed all website text, classes and etc. (all text from inspect element)

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Isn't that what its supposed to do? It runs and then exits.  You need to save the output to a file.

Comment: I did saved it as a file. It should print the href for each item in page 1... All it prints is Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text Make sure these are referencing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems lays at this line

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'atl '}):
```

according to [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) second argument `attrs` should be a dictionary with pairs like `{'attr_name': 'attr_value'}`. And `{'atl '}` is a `set`. Also, I think you mean `'alt'`, not `'atl'`. Try to use

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
```

There aren't `'a'` elements on page with attribute `'alt'`.